# Select multiple values and ORDER BY using Kotlin Exposed SQL DSL

Tags: sql, postgresql, kotlin, aggregate-functions, kotlin-exposed

Im trying to make the next query making use of Kotlin SQL Exposed framework.

```sql
SELECT interation_id, group_id, max(version)
FROM interaction
GROUP BY group_id;
```

I have a table of interactions, and each interaction group can have multiple interactions, each one marked with a different version. I want to retrieve the Interaction ID of each group with their latest version

Using exposed my query looks something like:

```kotlin
UserTable
    .slice(UserTable.id, UserTable.version.max())
    .selectAll()
    .groupBy(UserTable.versionGroupID)
    .toList()
```

yet I get an error of `UserTable.id must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`. But if i do this my group by will not return a single value for versionGroupId.

Extra input:
An example of what i would like to reproduce would be from this table.

| Interaction_id | group_id | version |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 | 3 |

I would like to get has a result Ids: 5 and 6. Those are the last version of each group ID.

| Interaction_id | group_id | version |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 | 3 |

Anyone that have make use of **kotlin Exposed SDK**(or maybe is a SQL exposed trouble on my side) can give me a hand? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `GROUP BY interation_id, group_id`?

Comment: @jarlh Yes, that makes the query dont throw an error but it return me all the values of the table(interaction_id is unique, group_id isnt). I want the interaction IDs of the group ID with the highest version

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: @jarlh example added!

Comment: Do you want a SQL or Kotlin answer?

Comment: @jarlh as said on the question. Is a kotlin question, yet using SQL aswell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a subquery to find the maximum version for each group in the `InteractionTable` and then joined this subquery with the original table to fetch the `interaction_id` for each group corresponding to the maximum version.

Try this

```
     val MaxVersionPerGroup = InteractionTable
    .slice(InteractionTable.versionGroupID, InteractionTable.version.max())
    .selectAll()
    .groupBy(InteractionTable.versionGroupID)
    .alias("MaxVersionPerGroup")

val maxVersionColumn = MaxVersionPerGroup[InteractionTable.version.max()]

val query = InteractionTable
    .join(MaxVersionPerGroup, JoinType.INNER, additionalConstraint = { 
        InteractionTable.versionGroupID eq MaxVersionPerGroup[InteractionTable.versionGroupID] and
        InteractionTable.version eq maxVersionColumn
    })
    .slice(InteractionTable.interation_id, InteractionTable.group_id, InteractionTable.version)
    .selectAll()

query.forEach { 
    println("Interaction ID: ${it[InteractionTable.interation_id]}, Group ID: ${it[InteractionTable.group_id]}, Version: ${it[InteractionTable.version]}")
}
```

Comment: Just tried this snipped. I get an `Field not found in original table fields` on `InteractionTable.version eq MaxVersionPerGroup[InteractionTable.version.max()]`

I have also added an example context to the code above

Comment: Answer updated with the fix

Comment: The fix didnt work. However after add an `alias` to the `version.max()` it worked as a charm. checked based on https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/issues/1294 .

Thanks a lot @TSCAmerica.com !

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql specific `DISTINCT ON` SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (group_id) interation_id, group_id, version
FROM interaction
ORDER BY group_id, version DESC;
```

Generic window function SQL query:

```
SELECT interation_id, group_id, version
FROM
(
    SELECT interation_id, group_id, version,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY version DESC) rn
    FROM interaction
) dt
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @TSCAmerica answer based on the DSL version you may need to use an `alias` over the `version.max()` reference. It may look like:

```kotlin
val maxVersion = InteractionTable.version.max().alias("max_version")
val maxVersionPerGroup = InteractionTable
            .slice(ArtifactTable.versionGroupID, maxVersion)
            .selectAll()
            .groupBy(InteractionTable.versionGroupID)
            .alias("maxVersionPerGroup")

val query = InteractionTable
            .join(maxVersionPerGroup, JoinType.INNER, additionalConstraint = {
                (InteractionTable.versionGroupID eq maxVersionPerGroup[InteractionTable.versionGroupID]) and
                    (InteractionTable.version eq maxVersionPerGroup[maxVersion])
            })
            .slice(InteractionTable.id)
            .selectAll()

query.toList.forEach {
    //Use the InteractioValue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because query doesn't know which interID need to use. Set it max and it show max id.

```
 UserTable
    .slice(UserTable.interID.max(), UserTable.gropeID, UserTable.version.max())
    .selectAll()
    .groupBy(UserTable.gropeID)
    .map {
        println("${it[UserTable.interID.max()]} ${it[UserTable.gropeID]} ${it[UserTable.version.max()]}")
    }
```